# Removing Mac Partition After Installing Linux And Deleting Mac OS X

Tags: ubuntu, partition, macintosh

Right now Linux Ubuntu is on 21.4 GB of my 110 GB disk space according to Disk Usage Analyzer. While downloading Linux I clicked the option that, I thought, would put Linux on my entire disk space and not just a small partition.

How is the simple way to put the remaining 90 GB of disk space into the "/" of Linux Ubuntu

(Not into computers, Linux was faster than Mac OS X for gaming)

Mac-Book Pro 2016 with Retina 8GB RAM

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/492054/how-to-extend-my-root-partition

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded Linux again and just made the largest partition my "/" folder. A lot faster now, although I have to redownload Steam it was highly worth it. Thank you @Elder Geek